# Find the boundary of the set of a circle and $y\leq x$

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

Is the boundary set of $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2\leq1, y\leq x\}$ consist of the $y= x$ line going through the middle of the circle, even though it is contained in that circle?

Would it be this?

$$
B=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2=1\}\;\cup\;\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: y= x\}
$$

Comment: No, the comma actually is interpreted as intersection, not union here.

Comment: Every point on the circle below the line $\{y=x\}$ is also a boundary point.

Comment: @fvim, consider drawing a figure of the region represented by the intersection of those inequalities in the plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boundary of your given set is isotopic to a 180 degree arc with a ray connecting the endpoints.

Your potential answer $B$ counts the points in the $(-x, +y)$ quadrant of the circle - but those points do not satisfy $y \le x$.

Comment: So the line y=x is a set of boundary points, and also the boundary of the circle for values below that line y=x (so for y<=x)

Comment: Yes, @fvim that is exactly right.

Comment: Then $B=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:(x)^2+(y)^2=1,y\leq x\}$, is that right?

Comment: Well.. The line y=x from $(-\sqrt2,-\sqrt2)$ to  $(+\sqrt2,+\sqrt2)$

Comment: You should be able to draw the answer without picking up your pencil.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, is that right now? I think I can draw that, its just the circle boundary under y=x and also y=x

Comment: y=x but only the part inside the circle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139061/discussion-between-fvim-and-will-sherwood).